# Reference for a combinatorial theorem

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

Is there a reference for this theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_theorem#Combinatorics?

I am unable to locate a reference. Google search does not spot this particular theorem well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears on page 99 of Wilf's *Generatingfunctionology*, which is available on his website [here](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html).

Comment: Do you know answer to this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1379604/a-simple-counting-question?

Comment: Yes, it's stated and proved in Wilf's textbook *Generatingfunctionology* which is freely available on his website.  You were looking for a reference for the theorem, right?

Comment: answer to linked question also.

Comment: Ah, I'll take a look at that now.  I didn't see it.

Comment: Why did you refer me to another question of yours only to delete it soon after I answered it?

Comment: I will update the question shortly. I think I made a mistake. I do not want to post two questions. There is a subtlety in what I was thinking. Sorry about this.